# Inline function in llvm IR

Tags: c++, llvm, inline, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am writing a llvm pass where I am trying to inline a call instruction. I am currently doing something like this

```
InlineFunctionInfo IFI;
InlineFunction(Call_Instruction, IFI)
```

The call is being inlined. But the issue is that the arguments/operands in the body of IR does'nt get replaced by the arguments of call function.

How to inline a **function in LLVM** with arguments replaced by arguments of call Instruction?